# Make docker container only accessible from a certain IP

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network

Right now, when I bind a docker container port to a port on my computer, it can be accessed through every IP address belonging to my computer.

I know this since I tried connecting to the port through another computer using my Docker host's static LAN ip address.

I want to restrict that specific container to be accessible exclusively by my docker host (127.0.0.1 or localhost). When I change my web server's IP to localhost, it becomes inaccessible from my docker host (probably because that makes it local to the container, not the host).

How can I make a docker container local to the host?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you run the container like this it will be accesable only from `127.0.0.1`

```
docker run --rm -it -p 127.0.0.1:3333:80 httpd
```

`--rm`: I use it for testing it removing the container after exit.
`-it`: interactive tty.
`-p`: port mapping, map 3333 on the host to 80 in the container and restrict access only from localhost.

The docker-compose equivalent would be:

```
services:
  db:
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:80:80"
```

Comment: How would I go about doing the same thing using docker-compose.yml?

Comment: I don't have time now to convert it to docker-compose, but this is direction for the solution.